# how do I track metrics in jmeter for 'java requests' with sub results?

Tags: jmeter

I am using jmeter with Java Request samplers. These call java classes I have written which returns a SampleResult object which contains the timing metrics for the use case. SampleResult is a tree and can have child SampleResult objects (SampleResult.addSubResult method). I cant seem to find a good way in jmeter to track the sub results so I can only easily get the results for the parent SampleResult.

Is there a listener in jmeter that allows me to see statistics / graphs for sub results (for instance see the average time across all sub results with the same name).

Answer (score 2):

I have just succeeded in doing this, and wanted to share it. If you follow the instructions I provide here, it will work for you as well. I did this for the summary table listener. And, I did it on Windows. And, I used Eclipse

Steps:

1. Go to JMeter's web site and download the source code. You can find that here, for version 3.0. 
   http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi

One there, I clicked the option to download the Zip file for the Source.

Then, on that same page, download the binary for version 3.0, if you have not already done so. Then, extract that zip file onto your hard drive.

2. Once you've extracted the zip file to your hard drive, grab the file "SummaryReport.java". It can be found here:  "\apache-jmeter-3.0\src\components\org\apache\jmeter\visualizers\SummaryReport.java"
3. Create a new class in Eclipse, then Copy/Paste all of that code into your new class. Then, rename your class from what it is, "SummaryReport" to a different name. And everywhere in the code, replace "SummaryReport" with the new name of your class.
4. I am using Java 8. So, there is one line of code that won't compile for me. It's the line below.

private final Map tableRows = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

You need to remove the <> on that line, as Java 1.8 doesn't support it. Then, it will compile

There was one more line that gave a compile error. It was the one below.

```
CSVSaveService.saveCSVStats(StatGraphVisualizer.getAllTableData(model, FORMATS),writer,` 
                        saveHeaders.isSelected() ? StatGraphVisualizer.getLabels(COLUMNS) : null);
```

Firstly, it wasn't finding the source for class StatGraphVisualizer. So, I imported it, as below.

```
import org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.StatGraphVisualizer;
```

Secondly, it wasn't finding the method "getLabels" in "StatGraphVisualizer.getLabels." So, here is what this line of code looked like after I fixed it. It is seen below.

```
CSVSaveService.saveCSVStats(StatGraphVisualizer.getAllTableData(model, FORMATS),writer);
```

That compiles. That method doesn't need the second argument.

Now, everything should compile.

5. Find this method below. This is where you will begin adding your customizations.

   @Override
   public void add(final SampleResult res) {

You need to create an array of all of your sub results, as I did, as seen below. The line in Bold is the new code. (All new code is seen in Bold).

```
public void add(final SampleResult res) {
        final String sampleLabel = res.getSampleLabel(); // useGroupName.isSelected());



**final SampleResult[] theSubResults = res.getSubResults();**
```

Then, create a String for each label for your sub results objects, as seen below.

```
**final String writesampleLabel = theSubResults[0].getSampleLabel(); // (useGroupName.isSelected());
        final String readsampleLabel =  theSubResults[1].getSampleLabel(); // (useGroupName.isSelected());**
```

Next, go to the method below.

```
JMeterUtils.runSafe(false, new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
```

The new code added is below, in Bold.

```
JMeterUtils.runSafe(false, new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Calculator row = null;
                **Calculator row1 = null;
                Calculator row2 = null;**
                synchronized (lock) {
                    row =  tableRows.get(sampleLabel);
                    **row1 = tableRows.get(writesampleLabel);
                    row2 = tableRows.get(readsampleLabel);**

if (row == null) {
                        row = new Calculator(sampleLabel);
                        tableRows.put(row.getLabel(), row);
                        model.insertRow(row, model.getRowCount() - 1);
                    }

                    **if (row1 == null) {
                        row1 = new Calculator(writesampleLabel);
                        tableRows.put(row1.getLabel(), row1);
                        model.insertRow(row1, model.getRowCount() - 1);
                    }

                     if (row2 == null) {
                        row2 = new Calculator(readsampleLabel);
                        tableRows.put(row2.getLabel(), row2);
                        model.insertRow(row2, model.getRowCount() - 1);
                    }**

                } // close lock
                /*
                 * Synch is needed because multiple threads can update the counts.
                 */
                synchronized(row) {
                    row.addSample(res);    
                }

                **synchronized(row1) {
                   row1.addSample(theSubResults[0]);      
                }**

                **synchronized(row2) {
                    row2.addSample(theSubResults[1]);
                }**
```

That is all that needs to be customized.

6. In Eclipse, export your new class into a Jar file. Then place it inside of the lib/ext folder of your binary of Jmeter that you extracted, from Step 1 above.
7. Start up Jmeter, as you normally would.
8. In your Java sampler, add a new Listener. You will now see two "Summary Table" listeners. One of these will be the new one that you have just created. Once you have brought that new one into your Java Sampler, rename it to something unique. Then run your test and look at your new "Summary Table" listener. You will see summary results/stats for all of your sample results.
9. My next step is to perform these same steps for all of the other Listeners that I would like to customize.

I hope that this post helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some of my plugin code which you can use as a starting point in writing your own plugin. I cant really post everything as there are really dozens of classes. Few things to know are:

- my plugin like all visualizer plugins extends the jmeter class
  AbstractVisualizer
- you need the following jars in eclipse to complile:
  jfxrt.jar,ApacheJMeter_core.jar
- you need java 1.8 for javafx (the jar file comes in the sdk)
- if you compile a plugin you need to put that in jmeter/lib/ext.
  You also need to put the jars from bullet 2 in jmeter/lib
- there is a method called "add(SampleResult)" in my class. This
  will get called by the jmeter framework every time a java sample
  completes and will pass the SampleResult as a parameter. Assuming you
  have your own Java Sample classes that extend
  AbstractJavaSamplerClient your class will have a method called
  runTest which returns a sampleresult. That same return object will be
  passed into your plugins add method.
- my plugin puts all the sample results into a buffer and only
  updates the screen every 5 results.

Here is the code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult;
import org.apache.jmeter.testelement.TestStateListener;
import org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.gui.AbstractVisualizer;

public class FxVisualizer extends AbstractVisualizer  implements TestStateListener {


    int currentId = 0;

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 5; 

    @Override
    public String getName() 
    {
        return super.getName();//"George's sub result viewer.";
    }

    @Override
      public String getStaticLabel()
      {
        return "Georges FX Visualizer";
      }



    @Override
    public String getComment() 
    {
        return "George wrote this plugin. There are many plugins like it but this one is mine.";
    }
    static Long initCount = new Long(0);
    public FxVisualizer()
    {
        init();
    }
    private void init()
    { 
        //LoggingUtil.debug("in FxVisualizer init()");
        try
        {

            FxTestListener.setListener(this); 
            this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            Border margin = new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 5, 10);
            this.setBorder(margin);
            //this.add(makeTitlePanel(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
            final JFXPanel fxPanel = new JFXPanel();
            add(fxPanel);
            //fxPanel.setScene(getScene()); 

            Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    initFX(fxPanel);
                }
           });


        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } 
    static FxVisualizerScene fxScene;
    private static void initFX(JFXPanel fxPanel) {
        // This method is invoked on the JavaFX thread
        fxScene = new FxVisualizerScene();

        fxPanel.setScene(fxScene.getScene());
    }

    final List <Event> bufferedEvents = new ArrayList<Event>();
    @Override
    public void add(SampleResult result) 
    {


        final List <Event> events = ...;//here you need to take the result.getSubResults() parameter and get all the children events.
        final List<Event> eventsToAdd = new ArrayList<Event>();

        synchronized(bufferedEvents)
        {
            for (Event evt : events)
            {
                bufferedEvents.add(evt);
            }


            if (bufferedEvents.size() >= BUFFER_SIZE)
            {
                eventsToAdd.addAll(bufferedEvents);
                bufferedEvents.clear();
            }
        }





        if (eventsToAdd.size() > 0)
        {
            Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    updatePanel(eventsToAdd);
                }
           });

        }       


    }



    public void updatePanel(List <Event> events )
    {

        for (Event evt: events)
        {
            fxScene.addEvent(evt);
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void clearData() 
    {
        synchronized(bufferedEvents)
        {
            Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    bufferedEvents.clear();
                    fxScene.clearData();
                }
           });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getLabelResource() {

        return "Georges Java Sub FX Sample Listener";
    }

    Boolean isRunning = false;

    @Override
    public void testEnded()
    {


        final List<Event> eventsToAdd = new ArrayList<Event>();

        synchronized(bufferedEvents)
        {
            eventsToAdd.addAll(bufferedEvents);
            bufferedEvents.clear();
        }

        if (eventsToAdd.size() > 0)
        {
            Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    updatePanel(eventsToAdd);
                    fxScene.testStopped();
                }
           });

        }       
    }
    Long testCount = new Long(0);
    @Override
    public void testStarted() {

        synchronized(bufferedEvents)
        {
                Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {                     
                        updatePanel(bufferedEvents);
                        bufferedEvents.clear();
                        fxScene.testStarted();
                    }
               });
        }

    }



    @Override
    public void testEnded(String arg0) 
    {
        //LoggingUtil.debug("testEnded 2:" + arg0);
        testEnded();
    }

    int registeredCount = 0;

    @Override
    public void testStarted(String arg0) {
        //LoggingUtil.debug("testStarted 2:" + arg0);
        testStarted();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK so I just decided to write my own jmeter plugin and it is dead simple. Ill share the code for posterity when it is complete. Just write a class that extends AbstractVisualizer, compile it into a jar, then throw it into the jmeter lib/ext directory. That plugin will show up in the listeners section of jmeter when you go to add visualizers.